# How to change the button in UIActionsheet

Tags: iphone

I have a UIActionsheet. I need to change the colour of the buttons in it.

```
-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive Button" otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];

    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];

    [popupQuery release];

}
```

The UIActionsheet displays as [this](http://ykyuen.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/uiactionview.png?w=584). a red button followed by 2 grey buttons and black cancel button. I need the first 3 buttons to be grey and the last button black. How can i do this programatically ?

Comment: Check this library out: https://github.com/gloomcore/UICustomActionSheet

Comment: So, isn't there any other way i could do this without adding a library to do this ? and will apple accept my app if i include this library ?

Answer (score 3):

Destructive buttons are automatically styled in red. When creating your action sheet, set the destructive button title to nil and only use the `otherButtonTitles` argument for the 3 gray buttons.